# Working with the time coordinates from a csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have made a measurement with a descent oscilloscope, and exported the fields to a csv file.

I want now to make a graphics drawing of this measurement with `pgfplots`.

The measurement starts at time `t0=-6e-7`second and ends at `tf=3.4e-6` second.

This time coordinate was not, unfortunately, exported with the voltage recorded from the oscilloscope input channels. It is inherent to this oscilloscope model.

So I went over to Mathematica and called for the following command:

```
t = Subdivide[-6*^-007, 3.4*^-006, 10000 - 1];
```

I.e., create a list of numbers 10000 entities long, that start at `-6e-7` and ends at `+3.4e-6`. I appended this new time data to my csv file so that it looks like the following:

```
% myData.csv
t,ch1,ch2
-0.0000006, -0.015810277,   -0.11067194
-0.000000599599959995999,   0.023715414,    -0.11067194
-0.000000599199919991999,   0.023715414,    -0.031620555
-0.000000598799879987998,   0.0039525693,   0.12648222
-0.000000598399839983998,   0.023715414,    0.047430828
...
and so on, 10000 rows long.
```

Compiling my pgfplots file,

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-6e-7,xmax=3.4e-6,
ymin=-5,ymax=30,
]
\addplot [green] table[x=t,y=ch1,col sep=comma] {path/to/file/myData.csv};
\addplot [blue] table[x=t,y=ch2,col sep=comma] {path/to/file/myData.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compilation time is quite long, and cause my TeXworks application to stop responding, but more importantly, I get a multiple of errors of the kind

```
NOTE: coordinate (7.32E-07,) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter. ( see also unbounded coords=jump).
```

I explicitly specified the domain for each axis, as you can see in the above code.

What is the reason for that? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Would it be better in this case to simply plot

```
(1,ch1(1) ), (2, ch1(2) ) , (3, ch1(3) ), (4,ch1(4) ) , .... , (10000,ch1(10000) )
```

?

**Edit:**

Is it related to the fact there is more than one time coordinate for which (supposedly) `t=-5.99e-7` seconds?

Look at the two screenshots below. Inside vim editor the second row for t says `-6e-7` and the second row inside the spreadsheet, which generated this file vim is showing, is `t=-0.000000599599959995999`.

[image: screenshots]

Comment: Having identical values in the file will not give you that warning, why would it. What does the file look like where t = 7.32e-7?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are ultimately correct. The file is missing some `ch1` and `ch2` values. Mistake for me. It happened because of the append and import tool of google sheets.
I will close this discussion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of a technical mistake I made when working on my TeX file. Torbjørn T. gave me insight for the problem, and so solved the technical issue. There is not any question or misunderstanding once the technical problem has been clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an error, `pgfplots` is just telling you that some of the lines in the data file hasn't been plotted. You should perhaps examine your data file, the one example you show says that `(7.32E-07,)` has been dropped from the plot. Note there is no y-value, which could mean there is no y-value in the file.

The example below shows the same note for the last line, reading `1, ,` .

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [green] table[x=t,y=ch1, col sep=comma] {
t,ch1,ch2
-0.0000006, -0.015810277,   -0.11067194
-0.000000598399839983998,   0.023715414,    0.047430828
1, , 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am carefully examining my csv file and it is ok regarding with what you propose. I am actually was a bit incorrect with what the data I described in the original post. I should update it now.